# prevent globbing of argument to bash script

Tags: find, arguments, glob

I want to invoke the "find" command inside myscript, using the arguments that I pass to myscript. But if I use wildcard characters with the "-name" argument and any file happens to match the string, the string is expanded to all the filenames, no matter what kind of "quotes" I 'use'.

In the shell, I want globbing, but not when I pass arguments to this script. Example:

```
~/u/tmp/JNK> ls -latTr
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  160 BNW  staff  5440 Jan 27 18:47:37 2018 ../
-rw-r--r--    1 BNW  staff     0 Jan 27 19:30:10 2018 Henry-James.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 BNW  staff     0 Jan 27 19:30:17 2018 Emily-Dickinson.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 BNW  staff     0 Jan 27 19:30:21 2018 for-Henry-James.txt
-rwxr-xr-x    1 BNW  staff    97 Jan 27 19:31:55 2018 myscript*
-rw-r--r--@   1 BNW  staff  6148 Jan 27 19:43:15 2018 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x    2 BNW  staff    68 Jan 27 19:44:51 2018 DIRECTORY/
lrwxr-xr-x    1 BNW  staff    19 Jan 27 19:45:09 2018 softlink@ -> for-Henry-James.txt
drwxr-xr-x    9 BNW  staff   306 Jan 27 19:45:09 2018 ./

~/u/tmp/JNK> find . -type f
./.DS_Store
./Emily-Dickinson.txt
./for-Henry-James.txt
./Henry-James.txt
./myscript

~/u/tmp/JNK> find . -type f -name "*James*"
./for-Henry-James.txt
./Henry-James.txt

~/u/tmp/JNK> cat myscript 

#!/bin/bash
for arg in $@
do
   printf '%s' "arg="
   printf '%s' "$arg"
   printf '\n'
done
find . $@


~/u/tmp/JNK> ./myscript -type f
arg=-type
arg=f
./.DS_Store
./Emily-Dickinson.txt
./for-Henry-James.txt
./Henry-James.txt
./myscript

~/u/tmp/JNK> ./myscript -type f -name "*James*"
arg=-type
arg=f
arg=-name
arg=Henry-James.txt
arg=for-Henry-James.txt
find: for-Henry-James.txt: unknown primary or operator

~/u/tmp/JNK> ./myscript -type f -name '*James*'
arg=-type
arg=f
arg=-name
arg=Henry-James.txt
arg=for-Henry-James.txt
find: for-Henry-James.txt: unknown primary or operator
~/u/tmp/JNK>
```

Is there an elegant solution?

Answer (score 3):

The solution appears to be to add one line

```
set -o noglob
```

to the script. Now we have

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o noglob
for arg in $@
do
    printf '%s' "arg="
    printf '%s' "$arg"
    printf '\n'
done
find . $@
```

and

```
~/u/tmp/JNK> ./myscript -name "*Jam*"
arg=-name
arg=*Jam*
./for-Henry-James.txt
./Henry-James.txt
~/u/tmp/JNK>
```